# Capturing cell values outside of cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I want to access some cell values outside of cellForRowAt.

```
  @IBAction func ShareClicked(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        print("Hello Edit Button")

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        let cell = TableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell

        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [cell.Books!, "I found this book", cell.Title!,"in the LitSwap app for :",cell.Price! ], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

I want to access cell.Books, cell.Title and cell.Price in a button function. However, with my solution above, I want to be able to capture any row in my tableViewCell and not just (row: 0, section: 0) but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Don't try to access cell information. It's a view, not your data. Access your data from your data model.

Comment: @rmaddy huh? How do I do that?

Comment: Access the same data model you use in all of the table view dataSource methods such as `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Just do as rmaddy has suggested. Though I'm really not sure what your question is. You know how to access it row:0, section:0...you can access any other indexPath like that e.g. row:10, section:2...

Comment: @Honey but I want the user be able to click on any cell they want and by me hard coding the row and section, any user will not be able to click on what ever cell they want

Comment: Then don't hard-code the row and section.

Answer (score 0):

In the cellforRowAtIndexPath, update the tag of button to the indexpath.row,
And in the button action method retrieve the data from the model based on the tag..

Comment: No, do not use tags. They will be wrong if the table supports adding, removing, or moving rows.

Comment: @rmaddy then  what should we use isntead?

Comment: @ArgaPK Click on the linked duplicate at the top of the question and see the answers.